# FreeRADIUS policy to restrict certain users trying to log on a specific device

Tags: freeradius

**What I have**: 
freeradius 2.1.10 on debian, configured to use a database.

**How it works now**:
There are many devices on the network and users, the users log on devices to configure them and so on. The users can log on to anything. For example some devices (ciscos) the user account on radius comes along with privileges (`cisco-avpair` attribute) that restrict what that individual can and cannot do on cisco devices.

**What I want freeradius to do in *addition*, for a specific special case**:
There's a special device that only select users should be able to authenticate into. Everyone else should be just denied access. (so, more strict than the cisco example above).

What I think I should be doing is first define my own attribute for example `company-special-privilege` so that I can set that for some users in the database with a value of `0` or `1`. Then define some policy in `policy.conf`.

**What I'm asking**:
Never done policies and I don't understand where they're applied in the rest of the freeradius config (where should I put my `special_access` policy). 
Also unsure how to formulate it but the following pseudocode should represent what I want:

```
special_access {
    if (request to log in $special_device_ip) {
        if ($username company-special-privilege) {
            reject #
        }
    }
}
```

From the above I don't know how to get the device IP or the attribute that the user is set with. I'm not doing a == 1 on the attribute in the second condition in case the user doesn't have the attribute as I don't know what that would imply but any user that doesn't have 1 must be rejected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put it in `raddb/policy.conf` inside the `policy {}` stanza. Then they can be referenced (by their name) as you would a normal module, in authorize, authenticate, post-auth etc...

Policies in FreeRADIUS are essentially macros, they're not functions, they don't take arguments.

Defining a special attribute to control policy decisions is fine, do it in `raddb/dictionary` unless you have an IANA number and want to spin your own custom dictionary. An easier way may just be to query SQL directly.

I'm not sure what you want to do specifically, but here's an example that may help... Modify as necessary

```
special_access {
    if ("%{Called-Station-ID}" == 'special device') {
        if ("%{sql:SELECT special_priv FROM table WHERE username = '%{User-Name}'}" != '1') {
            reject
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume then that I should have `special_access` in `authenticate`? I don't know what the csid will be reported as, will that hold the IP of said special device? I've seen some weird values filled in the accounting table but for other types of radius account..

Comment: It's best to stick to the standard AAA model. That is, policies for authorizing users go in authorize, policies for authenticating credentials provided by the user go in authenticate.

If the user is authenticating with credentials, then you'd list ``special_access`` and the module that could deal with those credentials, like pap, in ``authorize {}``, and then use pap again in ``authenticate {}``.

Comment: If that doesn't make sense, this page might help:

http://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/Concepts

Comment: Oh and it's impossible to know what the Calling-Station-Id will be, it's a text field, the NAS can stick anything it likes in there. It was just an example of something that'd identify the device.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to some info I found on http://linotp.org/doc/2.6/part-installation/integration/index.html you can use the following configuration if you use the nas table in the MySQL database. 
in the `nas` table you have IP ranges per device group, so if you device is in the specific IP range, the policy will be used:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM nas WHERE is = '1'; 
+----+------------------+-------------+-------+------------+----------------------------------+
| id | nasip            | shortname   | type  | secret     | description                      |
+----+------------------+-------------+-------+------------+----------------------------------+
|  1 | 192.168.1.0/24   | restricted  | other | *********  | only some users have access      |
+----+------------------+-------------+-------+------------+----------------------------------+
```

In the file `sites-enabled/default` you refer to the policy;

```
authorize {
 ...
 update request {
     FreeRADIUS-Client-Shortname = "%{Client-Shortname}"
 }
 my_policy
 ...
}
```

and in the `policy.conf` you write your policy. This policy check first the `nas` table for the *restricted* prefix and then checks if the user has sufficient rights

```
...
  my_policy {
    if (FreeRadius-Client-Shortname =~ /^restricted/) {
      if ("%{sql:SELECT moreaccess FROM radusergroup WHERE username = '%{User-Name}'}" != '1') {
        update reply {
          Cisco-AVPair := "shell:priv-lvl=1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
...
```

And of course in your `radusergroup` table where you're referring to in your SQL query you add an extra column where you allow specific users with extra rights.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM radusergroup WHERE username like 'peter%';
+------------------+--------------+----------+------------+
| username         | groupname    | priority | moreaccess |
+------------------+--------------+----------+------------+
| peter            | super-rights |        1 |       NULL |
| peter1           | super-rights |        1 |          1 |
| peter2           | super-rights |        1 |          0 |
+------------------+--------------+----------+------------+
```

In this case I wrote the policy like this;

- Normally already get the high privilege: `Cisco-AVPair := "shell:priv-lvl=15"`
- So if the user has a '1' in this case `peter1` is just getting the normal rights.
- If the user doesn't have a '1' (`!= '1'`), it will get the right mentioned in the policy.

  - instead of using `update reply` you can use `reject` to completely block access for this (`peter` and `peter2`) users.

it could get quiet complicated, but this works for me.